# Strange basic computation issue with numpy.int64 and/or numpy.float64?

Tags: python, numpy

I am getting a very weird and unexpected ERROR from python-numpy

I am working with the following libraries:

```
import os, glob, string, math, csv, json
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import scipy as sci
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import feedparser as fp
import cPickle as pickle
import networkx as nx
from urllib2 import urlopen
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
import patsy
```

The following code:

```
n,k = 2643605051, 648128.068241
print n,type(n)
print k, type(k)
nkvar = (k + 1)*(n + 2)/( (n+2) * (n+1)**2 )
print nkvar

n = np.int64(n)
k = np.float64(k)
print n,type(n)
print k, type(k)
nkvar = (k + 1)*(n + 2)/( (n+2) * (n+1)**2 )
print nkvar
```

Yields:

```
2643605051 <type 'int'>
648128.068241 <type 'float'>
9.27402694708e-14
2643605051 <type 'numpy.int64'>
648128.068241 <type 'numpy.float64'>
-0.00383719008751
```

The second answer is OBVIOUSLY wrong!  Could someone please help me understand what is going on?

Comment: Ok, sorry for blaming pandas.  The issue seems to be with numpy!  Here is an example:
`n,k = 2643605051, 648128.068241
print n,type(n)
print k, type(k)
nkvar = (k + 1)*(n + 2)/( (n+2) * (n+1)**2 )
print nkvar

n = np.int64(n)
k = np.float64(k)
print n,type(n)
print k, type(k)
nkvar = (k + 1)*(n + 2)/( (n+2) * (n+1)**2 )
print nkvar`

which yields:
`2643605051 <type 'int'>
648128.068241 <type 'float'>
9.27402694708e-14
2643605051 <type 'numpy.int64'>
648128.068241 <type 'numpy.float64'>
-0.00383719008751
`

Comment: Can you put that example in your question? It's near impossible to follow in a comment.

Comment: `int64` is 64-bit. Operations on it are restricted to 64 bits. `int` produces arbitrary-precision `long`s if the result doesn't fit into an `int`.

Comment: is there a way to set the default precision to int64 and float128 in NUMPY?

Comment: Is there a reason that you haven't canceled the common factor (n+2) in the numerator and denominator of your expression?

Comment: No reason.  This example is a simplification of the actual issue.  I guess I was sloppy simplifying the expression.  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are suffering from arithmetic overflow. With NumPy, for the sake of speed, [most operations do not check for arithmetic overflow](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.numeric.general/29300). The onus is on you to choose the proper dtype to avoid overflow.

```
import numpy as np

n,k = 2643605051, 648128.068241
nkvar = (k + 1)*(n + 2)/((n+1)**2 * (n+2))
print "In foo nkvar = ", nkvar, "  from (n,k) = ", (n,k)
# In foo nkvar =  9.27402694708e-14   from (n,k) =  (2643605051L, 648128.068241)       

n,k = np.int64(2643605051), np.float32(648128.068241)
nkvar = (k + 1)*(n + 2)/((n+1)**2 * (n+2))
print "In foo nkvar = ", nkvar, "  from (n,k) = ", (n,k)
# In foo nkvar =  -0.00383719005352   from (n,k) =  (2643605051, 648128.06)
```

**A workaround:** Since there is no NumPy integer dtype large enough to perform the computation without overflow, you'll need to convert `n` to a Python int first:

```
n = int(w.sum())
```

**Another alternative** is to change the `dtype` of `n` to `float64`:

```
n,k = np.float64(2643605051), np.float64(648128.068241)
nkvar = (k + 1)*(n + 2)/((n+1)**2 * (n+2))
print "In foo nkvar = ", nkvar, "  from (n,k) = ", (n,k)
# In foo nkvar =  9.27402694708e-14   from (n,k) =  (2643605051.0, 648128.06824099994)
```

Comment: is there a way to set the default precision to int64 and float128 in NUMPY?

Comment: When you define your arrays, you can supply the desired `dtype`. Or, after the fact, the dtype can be changed with `arr = arr.astype('int64')`. However, even `int64` is not big enough to avoid overflow in this case.